# How can I prevent "No such module 'Alamofire'" as an error in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

My Xcode keeps giving me the error "No such module 'Alamofire'" even though I've built and run it a few times, on this project. It seems like this happens randomly. I can usually solve it by quitting Xcode and reinstalling my pods in the project. However, this is annoying and a waste of time. Is this something other people are dealing with? Did I install it improperly? What is going on?

Comment: Are you sure you are opening the workspace and not the project?

Comment: Yes, absolutely sure. I was kind of hoping that was what I was doing wrong actually, because it would be an easy fix, but I'm opening the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I also encounter this problem. In my case, this is due to lack of disk space on mac os. When I free up enough space this problem is solved.

Comment: Sorry to sound like a total nOOb, but by disk space you mean RAM, correct? So if I try running fewer programs while I am programming, I should be less likely to see this problem occur?

Comment: He talks about disk space not about ram.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got the same problem with a different pod, Realm Swift. The answer to this was to go into Product > Scheme > Manage Scheme, then uncheck everything but the pod. After that, I built the project successfully. Then I went back into Manage Scheme and checked my project and unchecked the pod. I had to try a few different combinations before I got one working, but this solved the problem.

Comment: Share your podfile please.